# Copy entire row to a new sheet and change cell value based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have code which copies entire rows of data from one sheet (Quality Log) to another sheet(Appeal Log) based off of a cell value (Appeal Logged) in a Column V.

Previously it deleted that row from the originating (Quality Log) sheet.

I'm now looking to change the cell value to (Under Appeal) and then move it to the next sheet (Appeal Log).

I indicated with a ** my attempt to alter the code.

```vb
Sub CopyToAppealLog()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim K As Long
i = Worksheets("Quality Log").UsedRange.Rows.Count
j = Worksheets("Appeal Log").UsedRange.Rows.Count
If j = 1 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Actioned").UsedRange) = 0 Then j = 0
End If
Set xRg = Worksheets("Quality Log").Range("V3:I" & i)

On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For K = 1 To xRg.Count
    If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Appeal Logged" Then
        xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Appeal Log").Range("A" & j + 1)
        
        xRg(K, 22).Value = "Under Appeal" '**
        'xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete

        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Appeal Logged" Then
            K = K - 1
        End If
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next
   
'Call ResizeArchiveTable
      
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you actually want to flag the row in column `V` with `Under Appeal` (so it doesn't get copied twice) and then copy (not move) the row to the `Appeal Log` worksheet? Do you possibly mean *logged* instead of *lodged* (typo)?

Comment: @VBasic2008 my thoughts of changing the value to 'appeal logged' (typo) would act as that 'Flag' as you rightly put it to stop it from being copied any more. When I've run the code in the passed it gets stuck in this endless loop of copying the same line as I'm not deleting the row anymore. (commented out in the code above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Flag and Copy Rows

```vb
Sub CopyData()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Quality Log")
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("V3:V" & slRow)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Appeal Log")
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Dim drrg As Range: Set drrg = dws.Rows(dlRow)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim drCount As Long
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        If CStr(sCell.Value) = "Appeal Logged" Then
            sCell.Value = "Under Appeal"
            drCount = drCount + 1
            sCell.EntireRow.Copy drrg.Offset(drCount)
        End If
    Next sCell
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Rows copied: " & drCount, vbInformation

End Sub
```